# IIS logentries yesterday - 24 hours

Tags: performance, iis, logging, logparser

Is there anyone who can help with af logparser query?

I would like all yesterday's entries from the IIS log from 00:00:00 hours to 23:59:59 hours.

Someone who knows that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could try below query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*  
WHERE date>'2019-09-19' and date<'2019-09-20'
```